# accessing c++ map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am trying to access values from keys in a std:map in C++

Assume that aObject is valid
Mymap has several values.

```
map<myObject,int> mymap;
myObject aObject;
int value = mymap[aObject];
```

Do I have to redefine operator == for myObject?

What will happen if I don't redefine it?

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` requires that you either overload `operator<` for the key-type, or provide a comparator. Both have to implement a strict weak ordering. If you don't provide either, your program will not compile. If you implement them incorrectly (i.e. not as a strict weak ordering) you get garbage results (I actually don't know if this is actually undefined behavior in the strict sense).

Comment: ...or specialise `std::less` for the key type.